# INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE with Android project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am putting together an Android test app utilising the [Java SignalR SDK](http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/03/06/android-java-developers-signalr-sdk/), however whenever I try to test this app (via Eclipse) to my hardware device (Intel Atom) I get

> "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE".

The same app however deploys and runs OK in Intel Atom AVDs. Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out the problem was with using a pre-built jar file. Once I produced the jar locally, the problem disappeared.